# Exception in Hama BSP

Tags: java, apache, exception, bsp, hama

My hama throws the following exception during the input data partition phase before actually running my BSP job.  Can I know what are the possible root causes of this exception? Any suggestions about how to find out the root cause is appreciated.  Thank you!

```
13/11/06 03:50:50 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/11/06 03:50:50 INFO sync.ZKSyncClient: Initializing ZK Sync Client
13/11/06 03:50:50 INFO sync.ZooKeeperSyncClientImpl: Start connecting to Zookeeper! At masked-addr:33960
13/11/06 03:50:52 ERROR bsp.BSPTask: Error running bsp setup and bsp function.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization.accept(WritableSerialization.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.getSerialization(SerializationFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.getSerializer(SerializationFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:963)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:284)
    at org.apache.hama.bsp.PartitioningRunner.bsp(PartitioningRunner.java:217)
    at org.apache.hama.bsp.BSPTask.runBSP(BSPTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.hama.bsp.BSPTask.run(BSPTask.java:146)
    at org.apache.hama.bsp.GroomServer$BSPPeerChild.main(GroomServer.java:1246)
13/11/06 03:50:52 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping server on 33960
13/11/06 03:50:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 33960: exiting
13/11/06 03:50:52 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 33960
```

Comment: which hama and hadoop version you are using? also which OS you are using ?

Comment: I use hama v0.6.3 and Apache Hadoop Mapreduce v1.2.1., and it's running on linux.

Comment: can you provide which tutorial you are using for the installation and configuration of hama, because i have problem since last three week in hama, i used it in win8 with vmware player, hama v0.6.4 and hadoopv1.2.0

Comment: For the setup stuff, I think I mainly followed the hama and hadoop main website (https://hama.apache.org/, http://hadoop.apache.org/), specifically those getting started pages, but I have no experience on running them in vmware under win8.

Comment: does it work smoothly in psudu-distributed and other mode for you or you got some problems also in installation process?

Comment: I think it works smoothly (esp if you have some experience on hadoop.)  In my case, it took me two days to setup a cluster and wrete my first BSP codes, although I think the monitoring page of Hama could be improved a bit.

Comment: for me hadoop worked smoothly but while trying to run hama example got the connection error, can you please share which materials you used exactly and which version of hadoop and hama you used. thanks
i got the following error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912772/apache-hama-installation-error-on-ubuntu-14-04?noredirect=1#comment37084980_23912772

Comment: That's the exact versions I used.

Comment: actually i resolved the problem, you can find it here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912772/apache-hama-installation-error-on-ubuntu-14-04?noredirect=1#comment37212613_23912772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root cause.  This exception happens when at least one of the input files specified in the input paths is size 0.