# apache hama installation error on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hama

i want to install and run the hama using the hama installation guide which use port no 54310 in the whole process, but when i want to run some example on hama it gave me an error. i.e. retrying to connect to server: localhost/ 127.0.0.1:40000

here is my hama-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>bsp.master.address</name>
 <value>localhost</value>
 <description>The address of the bsp master server. Either the
 literal string "local" or a host[:port] (where host is a name or
 IP address) for distributed mode.
 </description>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>bsp.system.dir</name>
 <value>/tmp/hama-hduser/bsp/system</value>
 <description>The shared directory where BSP stores control files.
 </description>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>bsp.local.dir</name>
 <value>/tmp/hama-hduser/bsp/local</value>
 <description>local directory for temporal store.</description>
 </property>
<property>
<name>hama.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>/tmp/hama-hduser</value>
 <description>Temporary directory on the local filesystem.</description>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
 <description>
 The name of the default file system. Either the literal string
 "local" or a host:port for HDFS.
 </description>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

> I have already started HDFS, here is the error message after run the PI example.

```
hduser@ubuntu:/opt/hama$ /opt/hama/bin/hama jar hama-examples-0.6.4.jar pi
14/05/28 05:50:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:50:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:50:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:51:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:51:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:51:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:51:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:51:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:51:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/05/28 05:51:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:40000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:40000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:937)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:913)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:238)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:434)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:426)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:403)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:368)
    at org.apache.hama.bsp.BSPJobClient.init(BSPJobClient.java:230)
    at org.apache.hama.bsp.BSPJobClient.<init>(BSPJobClient.java:221)
    at org.apache.hama.bsp.BSPJob.<init>(BSPJob.java:57)
    at org.apache.hama.bsp.BSPJob.<init>(BSPJob.java:75)
    at org.apache.hama.examples.PiEstimator.main(PiEstimator.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hama.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hama.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hama.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hama.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:146)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:712)
    at org.apache.hama.util.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:204)
    at org.apache.hama.util.BSPNetUtils.connect(BSPNetUtils.java:375)
    at org.apache.hama.util.BSPNetUtils.connect(BSPNetUtils.java:347)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:364)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:408)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1600(Client.java:195)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hama.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:888)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: any body used hama before, plzzzzzzzzzzzzzz help

Comment: Checked in local mode?

Comment: i am following the local mode of this method                                               http://people.apache.org/~tjungblut/downloads/hamadocs/ApacheHamaInstallationGuide_06.pdf

Comment: do you know why it tried for 40000, because i set port to 54310 for hadoop and 54311 for mapreduce, and both of those working

Comment: In local it wont try to connect to localhost. May be you are trying in pseudo distributed mode. Try running with bsp.master.address set to local rather than localhost in hama-site.xml

Comment: what is difference b/w these modes?

Comment: Its clearly written in the docs. `. When submitting a job it will run a local multithreaded BSP Engine on your server.`

Comment: but i don't know why it didn't work for me, because i followed the exact procedure, and run map reduce task which worked but hama example didn't work

Comment: Didnt worked when local is set?

Comment: then this error occure "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4"

Comment: Can you please post the correct `hama-site.xml`. In the given one `localhist` is given. You need to change it to 'local'

Comment: i changed it to local but still have problem

Comment: Same error still occurring?

Comment: then error change like this "Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4"

Comment: @hanifs you are using a version of Hama that was compiled with a different version of Hadoop. My guess is that your installation of Hadoop uses Hadoop 2.x, while Hama was compiled for Hadoop 1.x. Make that consistent and it will work.

Comment: thanks, i will and will let you know if problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hama is compiled for the hadoop 1.x , so don't use hadoop 2.x

Comment: Is this answer this valid ? I ran into the same problem.

Comment: now the hama is available for both the versions of hadoop

Comment: I think that hama still works with 1.x. I downloaded the new version and tried to make it work with new hadoop but it gave me error. Changed the hadoop to older version and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

In fact whith your property  :

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>
   The name of the default file system. Either the literal string
   "local" or a host:port for HDFS.
  </description>  
</property>
```

You define the client adress to access to HDFS. Check in your core-site.xml what is the current value for this property.

I never used Hama but i guess you have to change this property :

```
<property>
  <name>bsp.master.address</name>
  <value>localhost:40000</value>
  <description>The address of the bsp master server. Either the
   literal string "local" or a host[:port] (where host is a name or
   IP address) for distributed mode.
  </description>
</property>
```

Maybe try to check the rules of your firewall, the port 40000 can be blocked or already use.

Comment: i tried to change the port but then i got another problem, "server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with version 4 client"

Comment: Upgrade your ipc version of your machine